# AngularJs: How to pass scope from within $http.get, into directive?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-directive

I'm having trouble trying to populate a vector map from data in my database, using angular & directives.

I have an angular dashboard webpage that needs to display an svg vector map of the United States populated with data from my database.  I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@tweededbadger/tutorial-dynamic-data-driven-svg-map-with-angularjs-b112fdec421d#.8y96arv1k), and everything works fine, however the tutorial passes hard coded values to the map.  I need to modify this to accept database values, & that's where I'm having trouble.  How can I make a call to my database and pass those values back to map, using a directive?

I'm still new to angular & this is my first experience with directives, but it appears as if the `$http.get` call happens after the directive, so I'm returning my db data too late.  Here's my code:

**App.js**

Here, I'm using both directives for this map functionality.  This all works fine:

```
var app = angular.module('dashboardApp', ['ngRoute', 'angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);

app.controller('dashboardController', DashboardController);

app.directive('svgMap',function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: '/Content/Images/Blank_US_Map.svg',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var regions = element[0].querySelectorAll('path');
        angular.forEach(regions, function (path, key) {
            var regionElement = angular.element(path);
            regionElement.attr("region", "");
            regionElement.attr("dummy-data", "dummyData");
            $compile(regionElement)(scope);
        })            
    }
}
});

app.directive('region', function ($compile) {    
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        dummyData: "="
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {            
        scope.elementId = element.attr("id");
        scope.regionClick = function () {                
            alert(scope.dummyData[scope.elementId].value);
        };
        element.attr("ng-click", "regionClick()");
        element.attr("ng-attr-fill", "{{dummyData[elementId].value | map_color}}");
        element.removeAttr("region");
        $compile(element)(scope);
    }
}
});
```

**DashboardController.js**

This is where my problem is.  Here, I'm returning data from my database via an `$http.get`.  I currently have my `$scope.createDummyData` function outside of this http.get & it works fine.  If I place that code inside my `$http.get` however, data doesn't populate.  And that's my problem:

```
var DashboardController = function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get('/Account/GetDashboardDetails')
    .success(function (result) {

        //need to place my $scope.createDummyData inside here

    })
    .error(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

var states = ["AL", "AK", "AS", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "DC", "FM", "FL", "GA", "GU", "HI", "ID", "IL",
        "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MH", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM",
        "NY", "NC", "ND", "MP", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PW", "PA", "PR", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VI", "VA",
        "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY"];
$scope.createDummyData = function () {
    var dataTemp = {};
    angular.forEach(states, function (state, key) {
        dataTemp[state] = { value: Math.random() }
    });
    $scope.dummyData = dataTemp;
};
$scope.createDummyData();
};
```

**HTML**

Finally, here's my html.  I don't feel anything here pertains to my issue, but I included it anyway, just in case:

```
<div class="container">
    <div svg-map class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="height:350px;"></div>
    <p>
        <button ng-click="createDummyData()" class="btn btn-block btn-default">Create Dummy Data</button>
    </p>
    <div class="regionlist">
        <div ng-repeat="(key,region) in dummyData">
            <div>{{key}}</div>
            <div>{{region.value | number}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I go about populating my map, via database data?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you make the HTTP call from the directive?

Comment: Try wrapping ng-if around div containing svg-map. Initially set the ng-if variable to false then once you get the data from backend and populate dummydata then set ng-if variable to true. This will start to render your template.

Comment: You've only shown how your assigning dummy data onto `$scope` in the `createDummyData` method. _How are you implementing the same logic for data returned from the server?_

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for exactly but might help.

I would create a service to grab the data (I'm assuming the HTTP to /Account/GetDashboardDetails returns a list of states) then call the service in your controller. Once the call is finished, you then call your create dummyDataFunction.

```
// Service

angular
  .module('dashboardApp')
  .service('$dataService', dataService);

dataService.$inject = ['$http']

function dataService() {

  var service = {

    getData : getData

  }

  return service;

  //////////

  function getData() {
    return $http.get('/Account/GetDashboardDetails')
    .then(function (result) {
      return result;
    },function(error) {
      return error;
    })
  }

}  


// Controller

var DashboardController = function ($scope,$dataService) {

  $scope.dummyData = [];
  activate();

  /////////

  function activate() {
    $dataService.getData()
      .then(function(states){

        var dataTemp = {};

        angular.forEach(states, function (state, key) {
          dataTemp[state] = { value: Math.random() }
        });

        $scope.dummyData = dataTemp;

      },function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

The link function of the directive executes before the `$http.get` XHR receives a response. One approach is to use `$watch` to wait for the data:

```
app.directive('region', function ($compile) {    
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            dummyData: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {            
            scope.elementId = element.attr("id");
            scope.regionClick = function () {                
                alert(scope.dummyData[scope.elementId].value);
            };
            element.attr("ng-click", "regionClick()");
            element.attr("ng-attr-fill", "{{dummyData[elementId].value | map_color}}");
            element.removeAttr("region");
            //Use $watch to wait for data
            scope.$watch("::dummyData", function(value) {
                if (value) {
                    $compile(element)(scope);
                };
            });
        }
    }
});
```

In the above example, the watch expression uses a [one-time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding) so that the `$compile` statement executes only once. If one wants the element to be re-compiled on every change of the data, it gets more complicated.

For more information on `$watch`, see [AngularJS $rootscope.Scope API Reference - $watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if the `link` function of your `svgMap` directive is called way before you ever make an HTTP get request.

What you have is that the `svgMap` directive is dynamically creating `region` directives which are bound to `dummyData` from the outer controller scope.

> Being *bound* to `dummyData` means Angular has already registered watchers for the bound property. Literally, this also means that this binding exists even before the properties are actually set on the scope elsewhere, i.e. the parent controller.

I suspect that the `$scope.dummyData` is not being assigned the returned data from the server properly.

From the code in your question, you are calling the `success` handler on the `get` request and getting the response back in the `result` variable. However, you've not mentioned how you are getting the data from the response. So, I reckon you might have mixed up the response from `.then()` callback with the `success()` callback:

***In case of the `.success()` callback:***

```
$http.get('/Account/GetDashboardDetails')
.success(function (result) {
    $scope.dummyData = result // data exists in the `result` itself
})
```

***In case of the `.then()` success callback:***

```
$http.get('/Account/GetDashboardDetails')
.then(function (response) {
    $scope.dummyData = response.data; // data is wrapped in `data`
})
```

If the above is not the case and you're sure enough that the returned data from the server is assigned to the scope properly, then try wrapping that portion of logic inside `$timeout()`. This triggers `$scope.$apply()` and ensures that changes in the `$scope.dummyData` are reflected properly in the view.

```
var DashboardController = function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
$http.get('/Account/GetDashboardDetails')
.success(function (result) {
   $timeout(function(){
      /* Do something here */
      $scope.dummyData = result;
   });
})
```